# Correct usage of WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a bean which implements `WebApplicationInitializer`

```
@Component
public class WebInit implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public WebInit() {
      ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        ...
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The bean is a `@Component`, and is getting instantiated by the container. It's constructor is called, but not the `onStartup` method. What is missing ?

The following  maven dependencies are defined:

```
org.springframework:spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-test-4.1.0.RELEASE
```

Thanks

Comment: since WebApplicationInitializer replaces web.xml so it should not have annotation of @component and do you have javax.servlet-api dependency in your code?

Comment: servlet-api is included. Removing Component, the WebApplicationInitializer implementation does not get initialized. Currently, after AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  is created, a Configuration class is registered- context.register(Config.class), so Spring instantiates beans either annotated with Component, or with Bean  in the Configuration class, Where does the WebApplicationInitializer  implementation fit into this? Thanks!